# CSS and JS are not rendered when index.jsp is set as welcome file

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp, servlets

I am facing a problem in jsp-servlet, when I am setting up my index.jsp as welcome-file (default page to run first as soon as the project gets run) at that time the CSS and JS files are not rendered.
My project Hierarchy is like this

-ProjectName 
        -User 
             -css 
             -js 
             -index.jsp

And also when I run my project the URL in the browser will be `localhost:8080/ProjectName` so here index.jsp is called but without CSS and JS files.

Edit: Finally, I had solved this issue by copying the CSS and JS to the root directory also. i.e. I have CSS and JS @ "User" as well as "ProjectName".

Comment: Can we see your jsp page where you have loaded css and js?

Comment: <link href="/ProjectName/User/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

This the css link written on my jsp page.

Comment: Why there is a slash before ProjectName if it is a root folder? Also it should be like-   <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: have you tried this  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: @RahulB: ProjectName is a root folder but still i need to add "/", i am also confused. And without it the CSS will not render...

Comment: @deogratias: I had tried but still the problem persist.

Comment: @kunalkakkad open the jsp page in your IDE right click on it and run it,and then check the browser console for errors

Answer (score 0):

Try with the context path,

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

will get you the path of the css file in the `css` folder. or with the `scriptlet`,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/style.css">
```

However, it is not recommended to you use the `scriptlets` in the jsp.

Comment: ${pageContext.request.contextPath} return "ProjectName" and defining CSS as above will not render it.